# How to verify if a checbox is checked for each individual value obtained from a MYSQL query using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a table where it fetches all possible rows from the database where the condition matches and for each data, there must be a checkbox near it and the submit button must verify the checked items. I could not get it to work in conjunction with rows from the database. It seems it could not detect the variable from the other page despite having include()

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `job_order` (
`SI_no` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `Date_Issued` date NOT NULL,
 `Date_Started` date DEFAULT NULL
 ) ;



 INSERT INTO `job_order` (`SI_no`, `Date_Issued`, `Date_Started`) VALUES
 ('2', '2018-12-19', '2018-12-26'),
 ('5', '2018-11-06', '2018-12-04'),
 ('7', '2018-12-01', '2018-12-13'),
 ('8', '2018-12-20', '2018-12-12');
```

jobrequestfilter.php

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Job Request Chart</title>




</head>


<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="navbar">


<div id ="wrap">
<div class="logo"></div> 



    <image name="b" class="b"></image>

</div>



    </div>
    </form>
<form action = "" method="post">
    <div id = "filterby">

       <input type="submit" id = "Email" class = "requestbutton" name = "Email" value="Email">
    </div>


    <table  id = "jobtable">
        <form method="post">
        <?php
            session_start();

            if(isset($_POST['OK'])){
                echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " .  $_SESSION['date_completed'] . "' );</script>";
                $aDoor = $_POST['id[]'];
                //check if checkbox is checked
                    if(empty($aDoor)) 
                            {
                                echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: CHeckbox not detected' );</script>";
                            } 
                            else 
                            {
                                $N = count($aDoor);

                                echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " .  $N . "' );</script>";
                                for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
                                {
                                    echo($aDoor[$i] . " ");
                                }
                                echo("</p>");
                            }


                //end checkbox validation
                include('database_email.php');

                }



              if (isset($_POST['Email'])){

                    include('database_email.php');

            }

            else{
                echo "<script>console.log( 'Nothing selected' );</script>";

            }

        ?>
        </form>
    </table>
    </form> 
</body>
```

database_email.php

```
<?php



    $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','dbname');
        if(!$conn){
        die('Could not Connect My Sql:' .mysql_error());
        }

        else{

            echo '<script>console.log("Connected to DATABASE")</script>';
        }

    $retrieve = "SELECT date_issued, date_completed from job_order;";
    $result = $conn-> query($retrieve);



    //table echo
    echo "<tr>
            <th>Date Issued</th>
            <th>Date Started </th> 



            <th>Approve?</th>
          </tr>";

//if statement
    if ($result-> num_rows > 0){
        //deploy the rows
        $counter = 0;
        while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()){

            $date_issued = $row["date_issued"];
            $date_completed = $row["date_completed"];
            $_SESSION['date_completed'] = $date_completed;
            echo 
            "<tr><td>" . $date_issued .
            "</td><td>". $row["date_completed"] .
            "</td><td>" . "<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'id[$counter]'  />" . "</td><tr>";

            $counter = $counter + 1;

        }

        echo "<tr><td>" ."<button type = submit  name = 'OK' value ='Submit' id = 'OK'  />" . "</td></tr>";



            //job update
                if(isset($_POST['OK'])) {
                    if(isset($_POST['id[]'])) {
                        echo('run your query here for box1 here');
                        header('database_email.php');

                    } 
                } else {
                    echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " .  $row['date_issued']  . "' );</script>";
                    header('database_email.php');
                }




    }

    else{

        echo "<tr><td> 0 results </td></tr>";
    }

?>
```

My solution was to echo a checkbox for each data obtained from the query, then a submit button to verify if the checkbox is checked, however I seem to have difficulty in manipulating the data using php alone. Should I resort to using jquery for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a few problems with your code.

1. Doesn't look like you have a unique identifier for the database for each order (could be SI_no)
2. You don't have a column that lets you know if the order has been processed.

I tried running over your code but honestly due to the indentation and having structural issues within your code it was easier to show an easier way of doing it. The code I am posting hasn't been tested but let me know if there are any issues.

What do you need to do? First things first is you need to create 2 more columns in your DB Table. ID and Checked.

ID should be int(255) - auto increment - primary. This creates a unique identifier so you know which row to delete, edit or select when dealing with specific orders.

Checked should be int(1) - default = 0. This will act as an identifier to let you know if this has been processed in your form. 0 being unprocessed, 1 being processed. simple.

Next create a new file called: db_c.php (code below)

```
<?php

define ( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define ( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
define ( 'DB_PASS', '' );
define ( 'DB_NAME', 'dbname' );


class db_c{  
    public $mysqli;
    function __construct() {
          $this->mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
          if(!$this->mysqli){
            die('Could not Connect My Sql:' .mysql_error());
          }
    }
    function complete_orders($orders){
        $processed = array();
        if(is_array($orders) && !empty($orders)){
            if(isset($orders['order-complete'])){
                foreach($orders['order-complete'] as $ids){
                    $sql = "UPDATE `job_order` SET `checked`= 1 WHERE `ID` = ?";
                    if($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql)){
                        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
                            if($stmt->execute()){
                               array_push($processed, $id);  
                            }
                    }
                }
                return $processed;
            }else{
                return 0; //No orders selected
            }
        }else{
            return 0; //Nothing to process
        }
    }
    function return_orders(){
        $orders = array();
        $sql = "SELECT `ID`, `SI_no`, `date_issued`, `date_completed`, `checked` FROM `job_order` WHERE `checked` != 1";
        if($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql)){
                if($stmt->execute()){
                    $stmt->bind_result($ID, $SI_no, $date_issued, $date_completed, $checked);
                    $stmt->store_result();
                    while($stmt->fetch()){
                           $orders[$ID]['SI_no'] = $SI_no;
                           $orders[$ID]['Issued'] = $date_issued;
                           $orders[$ID]['Completed'] = $date_completed;
                           $orders[$ID]['Checked'] = $checked;
                    }
                    return $orders;
                }else{
                    return 1;
                // failed to execute
                }
        }else{
            return 0;
            // failed to prepare
        }
    }
    function orders_2_table(){
        $unchecked = $this->return_orders();
        if(is_array($unchecked) && !empty($unchecked)){
            //returned results, build rows
            $table = '';
            foreach($unchecked as $id => $dets){
              $table .= '<tr><td>'.$dets['SI_no'].'</td><td>'.$dets['Issued'].'</td><td>'.$dets['Completed'].'</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="order-complete[]" value="'.$id.'"  /></td></tr>';  
            }
            return array('Rows'=>$table, 'Count'=>count($unchecked));
        }elseif(!is_array($unchecked)){
            if($unchecked === 0){
                return array('Rows'=>'<tr><td colspan="3">Error (SQL) </td></tr>', 'Count'=>0);
            }else{
                return array('Rows'=>'<tr><td colspan="3">Error (EXE) </td></tr>', 'Count'=>0);
            }
        }else{
            return array('Rows'=>'<tr><td colspan="3">All Orders Completed </td></tr>', 'Count'=>0);
        }
    }

}
?>
```

This file creates a Database Class that allows easy access for you, whether you want to select, update, delete etc. You can put the functions in here and easily call them when you need them (as long as you include this file in the page you want to use it). 
Scrap File: database_email.php (no longer needed)
For your jobrequestfilter.php you will need to update the code to:

```
<?php 

session_start();
include 'db_c.php';

$dbc = new db_c();
$msg = '';
if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['process_orders'])){
    $process = $dbc->complete_orders($_POST);
    if(is_array($process) && !empty($process)){
        $msg = '<tr><td colspan="3">Successfully Processed '.count($process).' Orders</td></tr>';
    }
}

$data = $dbc->orders_2_table();

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Job Request Chart</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navbar">
            <div id ="wrap">
                <div class="logo"></div> 
                <img id="b" class="b">
            </div>
        </div>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div id="filterby">
               <input type="submit" id="Email" class="requestbutton" name="Email" value="Email">
            </div>
        </form>
        <form method="post">
            <table id ="jobtable">
                <tr><th>SI no.</th><th>Date Issued</th><th>Date Started </th><th>Approve?</th></tr>
                <?php echo $msg ?> 
                <?php echo $data['Rows'] ?>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="process_orders" value="Process Orders" /></td><td>Count:<?php echo $data['Count'] ?></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is happening? Well in your code you had quite a few errors from checkbox inputs not having names to multiple forms within forms etc. This cleans up all the code and makes it super simple to read and find out what is going on.

Few things to consider:
Not sure what you were planning on doing with

```
<input type="submit" id="Email" class="requestbutton" name="Email" value="Email">
```

But I left it there for you to create your own function etc. currently it does nothing.
Every time you call

```
$dbc = new db_c();
```

The contruct function within the class is called, connecting you to the DB.

```
function __construct() {
          $this->mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
          if(!$this->mysqli){
            die('Could not Connect My Sql:' .mysql_error());
          }
}
```

If you have any questions let me know we can go to chat and I can help explain it a bit more if you need.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the correction btw. I gave your code a try and added some console logs. It returns 0 at line 32 of the db_c.php file based on the logs despite having checked something

Comment: Hey there was a small typo $order['order-complete'] should be $orders['order-complete'] on line 20 and 21.